# How can I decrease the value of $x in every 12 hours using PHP?

Tags: php

I took a variable `$x` and suppose the value of `$x` is `12`.

Now I want to decrease the value of `$x` by `1` in every `12` hours.

I tried many ways to do it. But I have no idea how to do this.

I tried this code:

```
for($x = 12; $x >= 0; $x--) {
    sleep(3); //this was done for testing in every 3 second
    echo $x;
}
```

The value of `$x` should not be less than `0`.

This code didn't work. It's giving me a very big number.

Comment: When you do `echo $x;` there is no space or new lines after each value. This means you will just get `1211109...`

Comment: Change `echo $x;` to `echo $x . PHP_EOL;`: http://prntscr.com/yhr0rr

Comment: the reason you are getting a big number is echo doesn't add line breaks, so every output get printed horizontally one after the other. And the next biggest issue is, What are trying to achieve exactly? running a for loop for 12hrs is like someone ask you to work for a whole year without taking a break. Use CRON job for periodic tasks